# What is the front-end performance differences of CSS loading types?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, external, download, inline

Magento 1.9, comparatively speaking, What are the front-end performance issues between types of loading CSS as:

- `external`
- `internal`
- `inline`
- as a `style block` (CMS blocks).

Thank you so much for your expertise !

Answer (score 0):

`external` : Not the best one : this adds additional HTTP requests and can delay rendering of the page.

`internal` : The best one : No HTTP request needed, the file is cached in browser in the first load for all pages, no need to load the file for each page.

`inline` : this css will be only loaded for that page and not all the pages and cannot be cached by the browser and re-used for another page.

`as a style block`: I don't know what you mean by this, but The **recommended** way is the second `internal`, you create your `custom.css` file in your current theme : `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/css/custom.css`, then you declare it in layout `<head>` part in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` and everythink will be fine.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  What I meant by 'a style block' is that I make CMS blocks that only contain CSS between style tags. Then I add them to my CMS page via a Widget. I have also started doing this with Jquery. I do it as a way of organizing. The reason is that I have a hard time finding the correct files to put the correct code in. The file system of magento varies so much and I always seem to be guessing as to if I am in the correct file. I have a ton to learn so thank you so much for your insightful, professional and expert knowledge.